# How to sum values from Map snapshot Flutter Firebase to get Total

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
 Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 4.0,
                                      ),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "\$${_productMap['price']}",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 16.0,
                                            color: Theme.of(context)
                                                .accentColor,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                      ),
                                    ),
```

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qle7W.png)

I Want to get Total from Price in realtime from firestore... any ideas?

Comment: Where is your list of products ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sum =0;
for(int i=0; i< _productMap.lenght; i++){
sum = _productMap['price'][i] + sum; 

}
```

After Completing the loop you will get your total sum !

Comment: Are you sure no typo in `_productMap.lenght` ? Also do you think your answer semantically make sense ?

Comment: Yes , Example :     List<Weight> weightData =
  mapData.entries.map( (entry) => Weight(entry.key, entry.value)).toList();

Comment: then we can Iterate the value and get the total sum

Comment: But do you really know his products list structure ?

Comment: He can convert his map to list structure and get the result

Comment: You still don't get what I mean. I am simply trying to say that you cannot guess OP data structure. Unless he gives it himself

Comment: Im not Guessing Im Trying to give him a way that if he wish he can do it for his desire result thats it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227453/discussion-between-dm-tr-and-tasnuva-oshin).

Comment: Hello everybody, and thank you for your answers! right now with the code you provide me, i having this issue: Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'.